# beautiful soup borders not being replaced

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to replace all instances of 'border: 1px' with 'border: 0px' in my beautiful soup project.

I include this function:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('work.html'), 'rb'), 'lxml')
try:
    for border in soup.find_all(text='border: 1px'):
        fixed_text = unicode(border).replace('border: 1px', 'border: 0px')
        border.replace_with(fixed_text)
except:
    pass
```

But the resulting html still has the borders.  Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the `border: 1px;` text located? In `<style>` tag, or in `style` attribute? Can you edit your question and post sample of HTML and expected output?

Comment: The `text` argument is only going to find elements that contain the text `border: 1px`, rather than elements with an attribute (ex. `style`) whose value is `border: 1px`.  I assume you want the latter, since you're expecting the replacement to affect border properties. In which case you will need to do something like `soup.find_all('div', {'style': 'border: 1px'})`.